# Yarn lock file resource source changed from registry.yarnpkg.com to registry.npmjs.org

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I recently npm installed a package into my Ruby on Rails application. The installation changed my yarn.lock file. Specifically, the "resolved" field for all my resources have changed from yarnpkg.com to npmjs.org.

From this:

```
d3-dsv@1:
  version "..."
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/d3-dsv/-/d3-dsv-1.0.8.tgz#..."
  integrity ...
```

To this:

```
"d3-dsv@1":
  "integrity" "..."
  "resolved" "https://registry.npmjs.org/d3-dsv/-/d3-dsv-1.1.1.tgz"
  "version" "..."
```

Is there a problem with these changes in this yark.lock file? Should I have done some yarn alternate to npm installing?

Comment: For what it's worth, I bypassed a similar issue by removing the relevant entry (the one using the npmjs.com registry) from the lock file and running `yarn` again. This should be enough to resolve the issue as I assume yarn will attempt to resolve the dependency from its own registry first.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this issue by re-running `yarn` again.

---

To accomplish this, follow the steps below.

1. Remove the [registry.npmjs.org](https://registry.npmjs.org/) section in your `yarn.lock` file.
2. Run the `yarn` command again.

   ```
   $ yarn
   ```

   This should rewrite the `yarn.lock` to change the registry from npm to Yarn.

---

The steps above should rewrite the `yarn.lock` file, and change the registry and text from npm to Yarn.

Answer (score 2):

It might be something related to where are you getting the packages from.

You can find out by typing: -> yarn config get registry

sometimes the registry is npmjs.org and that could be the reason why is getting changed in the yarn.lock.

So, you could set the registry to -> https://registry.yarnpkg.com by typing:

yarn config set registry https://registry.yarnpkg.com

then delete the yarn.lock file and retry again running yarn.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using only public packages in your application then this will not cause many problems.** You can go about your business as it is.
Although there might be some complications when you authenticate for any of them at any point. 
If you are using any private repositories, you have to re-register your packages with `yarn` and add credentials to them.

**The following steps will help you.**

1. Setup a private repo on [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/) and add a scope and your package ***(let's name it `boo`)***
2. Create a new project locally and upload it to the npm registry ***(let's call it `blimp`)***
3. So when they are updated it will be `@boo/blimp`
4. Add the package to your new applications `package.json` by installing `yarn add @boo/blimp`
5. Remove the `node_modules` ***(`rm -rf node_modules`)***
6. Try `yarn install` if there is an error in the lock file try re-creating one as follows

> sed -ie 's,registry.yarnpkg.com/@boo,registry.npmjs.org/@boo,' yarn.lock
> 7. If that omits an issue like `Request failed` or something in that alley, try following
> yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org

At this point, you have tried lots of options. If this is still an issue in your system then you might have to move to `npm` package management. Follow the [yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) repository for more updates.

Similar issues

- [yarn.lock should not include base registry](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3330)
- [Support protocol-relative registry](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4347)
- [Support for registry URLs without trailing slash](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/4350)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this happened to me because I installed something with `npm install` instead of `yarn`. I recognized my mistake, `npm uninstall`ed the package, then `yarn add`ed the package, but then every entry in yarn.lock was changed to use npmjs.org instead of yarnpkg.com.

I did not commit the changes to source control, and the problem disappeared after I...

1. Deleted package-lock.json
2. Reverted the change to package.json in source control (i.e. removed the new package)
3. Reverted all changes to yarn.lock in source control
4. `yarn add`ed the package again

I am unsure if using `npm install` followed by `yarn add` is really what triggered the problem. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, not only were the "resolved" fields updating (not all, most); sometimes the dependency names and "version" fields were too.

After updating the package.json, I ended up `npm uninstall`ing the package, and `yarn add`ing it instead. Then I reverted back to the old yarn.lock file (from the repo) and then `yarn install`ed.

Not sure which combo of these actions actually is the key, but my yarn.lock was updated with just the relevant dependencies.